# exporting class from dll error

Tags: c++, dll

I want to expose only the CreateSort() for the client. it was to create an object for the implementation of the sort class i.e imSort then return it to the client.but the compiler says that it cannot create an object of an abstract class eventhough all the functions have been defined in the derived class.

```
/////sort.h

class __declspec(dllexport) Sort {
public:
virtual int* BSort() const=0;
virtual void getdata() const=0;
};

extern "C" Sort *CreateSort();

/////imSort.h
#include "Sort.h"
class imSort : public Sort{
private:
int i,j,num;
int temp;
int *a;
public:
imSort();
int* BSort();
void getdata();
}

/////imSort.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "imSort.h"
Sort *CreateSort()
{
return new imSort(); /* object of abstract class type "imSort" is not allowed: */
}
imSort::imSort()
{
i=j=num=0;
*a=0;
}

void imSort::getdata()
{
std::cout<<"\nEnter the number of elements..";
std::cin>>num;
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    std::cin>>*a;
    *(a++);
}
}
int* imSort::BSort()
{
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    for(j=i+1;j<num;j++)
    {
        if(*(a+i)<*(a+j))
        {
            temp=*(a+i);
            *(a+i)=*(a+j);
            *(a+j)=temp;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: This is an elaborate joke, yes?

Comment: funny, we have to find the question and the answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you learning C++ from [a good introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642)?

Answer (score 2):

Your base class has:

```
virtual int* BSort() const=0;
virtual void getdata() const=0;
```

But your derived class has:

```
int* BSort();
void getdata();
```

Repeating the `virtual` keyword is optional, but without the `const` these are *separate* functions, *unrelated to the virtual base functions*.

As a result, those pure virtual functions remain un-overridden in the derived class, and so `imSort` (silly name for a type if you ask me) is still abstract.

Your fixed derived class definition is thus:

```
class imSort : public Sort {
   private:
      int  i, j, num;
      int  temp;
      int* a;

   public:
      imSort();
      int* BSort() const;     // <--- const
      void getdata() const;   // <--- const
};                            // <--- ;
```

<sup>(Notice how indentation improves the legibility of your code? And you forgot the `;` at the end of your class definition.)</sup>

---

**Please write a fully-formed question next time, and reduce your problem to a minimal testcase.**

Comment: added the const's...but now i get a compiler error for int* imSort::BSort() 
declaration in imSort.h is incompatible..

Comment: Your function definitions need to match, too, so: `int* imSort::BSort() const { ... }`. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: @Janak: I am not familiar with a C++ book called "essential com". Get one from [this list of recommended resources](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources) so that you can learn C++ properly!

Comment: @Janak - If you mean "Essential COM" by Don Box it's a good, if old, book for COM programming. You should also get a good general C++ book from the list Tomalak posted.

Answer (score 0):

If the virtual functions in the abstract `Sort` class are declared `const`, so should the implementations in the `imSort` class, but they are not.

So just add const here and there...